# MongoDB $geoNear decrease accuracy of distance return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, geonear

I'm performing a query on my user model in MongoDB and want to order the search results first by their distance in kilometres (using the `$geoNear` operator), and then by their last login time. The problem is, the distance attribute is returned as metres in a float variable, which is *too accurate*.

This means that my results are ordered like this:

```html
+----------------+------------------------+
|    distance    |  lastLoggedInTime      |
+----------------+------------------------+
|    1700        |  16 hours ago          |
|    1700.1      |  4 hours ago           |
|    2220        |  3 months ago          |
|    2220.5      |  1 day ago             |
+----------------+------------------------+
```

Those same values, where `km = Math.ceil(distance / 1000)` would order like this:

```html
+----------------+------------------------+
|    km          |  lastLoggedInTime      |
+----------------+------------------------+
|    2           |  4 hours ago           |
|    2           |  16 hours ago          |
|    3           |  1 day ago             |
|    3           |  3 months ago          |
+----------------+------------------------+
```

Which is what I want. I've made the values more readable to highlight the issue I'm facing. The actual values would look more like this:

```
{
    distance: 2234.3715776698273,
    lastLoggedInTime: '2019-07-13T02:14:30.173Z'
}
```

I've tried changing the `distance` attribute myself:

```
      user.distance = Math.ceil(user.travel.distance / 1000);
```

But since `distance` is added by the `$geoNear` inside the search query itself, I can only access it after the query runs. So the results are already sorted undesirably by the time I have access to it.

There is also the `distanceMultiplier` attribute, which I can attach to my query like this:

```
      $geoNear: {
        spherical: true,
        includeLocs: 'loc',
        distanceField: 'distance',
        distanceMultiplier: 0.001,        
        near: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [lng, lat]
        },
        ...
      }
```

But the result is still returned as a float, (2234.3715776698273 becomes 2.2343715776698273), which has the same problem. What are my other options?

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the operation to an aggregation and then using [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) to create and sort by a truncated distance field. The $project stage would use [$trunc](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/trunc/) to provide the simplified distance field.

For example:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  { "$geoNear" : {
    {
        spherical: true,
        includeLocs: 'loc',
        distanceField: 'distance',
        near: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [lng, lat]
        },
        ...
     }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "truncated_distance" : { "trunc" : [ "$distance", 0 ] }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort" : {
      "truncated_distance" : 1, 
      "lastLoggedInTime": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it now. I assume `$value` would need to be changed to `$distance` in my case?

Comment: Whoops. Correct, I think that would be $distance. I'll update it.